# Unable to open sql database error - to read lines into datagridview

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have an application that opens a database from a user inputted path, the user then scans a barcode into a textbox and the app should search for this number in the database and return the corresponding row of data. Currently the app works perfectly for Access databases using oleDB and I am writing the code for accessing sqlite databases using sqLite but I am getting an error message from the code `Error : unable to open the database`. Below is the code, any help appreciated as I am not overly familiar with databases!

```
    private void txtScannedValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtScannedValue.Text.Length == 15)
        {
            try
            {
                string dbPath = databasePathBox.Text;
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(dbPath);
                

                //open database to read
                if (extension == ".mdb" || extension == ".accdb")
                {
                    queryAccessDB(dbPath);
                }
                else if (extension == ".db")
                {
                    querySqlDB(dbPath);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("database extension not recognised");
                }
            }
                catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

public void querySqlDB(string sqlDBpath) 
    {
        // create a new database connection:
        string cnctstring = string.Format("data source={0};version=3;new=true;read only=true;", sqlDBpath);
        SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn = new SQLiteConnection(cnctstring);
        // open the connection:
        sqlite_conn.Open();

        populateDGVfromSQl(sqlite_conn);

        sqlite_conn.Close();
    }

        public void populateDGVfromSQl(SQLiteConnection sqlite_conn) 
    {

        try
        {
            SQLiteCommand sqlite_cmd = sqlite_conn.CreateCommand();
            sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Production where IMEINumber=$scanned";
            sqlite_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$scanned", txtScannedValue.Text);

            SQLiteDataReader sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(sqlite_datareader);

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.DataSource != null)
                    {
                        ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).ImportRow(dt.Rows[0]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No Data Found");
                }

                //reset textBox
                txtScannedValue.Text = "";

            }
            sqlite_conn.Close();

        }
        catch(SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Can not open connection ! ErrorCode: {ex.ErrorCode} Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error 3:" + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: the obvious question is 'is that the correct path and do you have rights to it?' Change the MessageBox to `.Show(e.ToString());` so we get the whole exception. You can copy from the MessageBox using `ctrl-c`, honestly it will copy the text for you. Put it in the question

Comment: -
code = CantOpen (14), message = System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException (0x800007FF): unable to open database file

   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, String vfsName, SQLiteConnectionFlags connectionFlags, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum openFlags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool)

   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()

   at CSV_Generator_App.mainForm.querySqlDB(String sqlDBpath) in C:\Users\ellak\Desktop\CSV Generator App\mainForm.cs:line 104 `(line is sqlite_conn.Open();)`

Comment: googling around the general consensus is disk IO error. Can you copy the file ?

Comment: Moving the file to my desktop worked. Is it not possible to open the sql database from a drive? It's just the user may not have access to the file location

Comment: what do you 'from a drive'? You can put sqlite DB wherever you like, but it must be read write. and it must be mounted

Comment: I copied the database from say the R: drive which is from a work server just to my desktop and it worked. It should be read write where it is originally

Comment: Yes it should work, maybe you dont have write access, are you sure the drive is mapped as a letter. That the path is correct. Are you running this in an odd way (task schedulr, web server....)? the mapping might not exist in that case

Comment: I will have to double check if I have write access, can't think of anything else wrong. I have double checked the paths. There4 is another database on the drive which is in another winforms app with the same issue, should I be able to access that database?

Comment: Thank you for the help with that much anyway, it has pointed me in a good direction I think